# formtastic render form fragment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial, formtastic

Is there any way to render forms fragments with formtastic?

I have some checkboxes in my form which come from a one-to-many relationship. 
So let's suppose a User form with a one-to-many Roles relationships. My formtastic form would look like

```
  <%= semantic_form_for @user] do |f| %>
    <%= f.inputs "Details" do %>
      <%= f.input :name %>
      <%= f.input :lastname %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.inputs "Roles" do %>
      <%= f.input :roles, :as => 'checkbox' %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

Now the line:

```
<%= f.input :roles, :as => 'checkbox' %>
```

Will output checkboxes for one-to-many. This works fine. But now I need to achieve some ActionController that outputs just the checkboxes... with no form and fieldset around. So that I can use it in my Ajax calls and update the "Roles" fieldset with fresh rendered checkboxes dinamically.

Any ideas? I'm stuck and can't figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if anyone had this need... anyway since nobody replied I found a solution by my self.
To render form fragments in the view (or partial view) file:

```
<% ref = nil %>
<% semantic_form_for [:admin, @user] do |f| %>
  <% ref = f %>
<% end %>
<%= ref.input :roles, :as => :check_boxes, :required => false %>
```

Notice that only the last line actually outputs something, previous lines don't.

Experienced Rubyst or maybe even newbies may laugh at this... but I'm a noob(Ruby) and this is the best I could come up with. If any of you can tell a better way to do it I will be more than happy to learn.